# Window.open opens new window but server says "URL not found". Is there a way to capture that situation?

Tags: javascript

I have app that uses Google Books API to grab some informations. Besides grabbing informations it also connects to WEB Page of chosen book. The problem is as follows: there are two subdomains with books. One has(I guess) really all books and the second only some (but the second shows more info!).

```
const showDetailedInfo = (item, redirect) => {
  const id = item[item.length - 1];
  console.log(item);
  if (id && (typeof id === "string" || id instanceof String)) {
   
    const path = 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=' +id;
       
    try{let newWindow = window.open(path, "_blank");}
    catch(err){
      let result ={error: true, errorMessage:err.message}
      store.dispatch({ type: "RECEIVE_BOOKS", payload: result });
      redirect.error();

    }
  }
};
```

I would like as follows: if the book is not in second (with more info) subdomain, I will go to page with less info. The problem is that I can not catch that event.
When the book is not in second I receive such the screen:
https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=aGcBwwEACAAJ
And valid variable newWindow (acc to MDN it should revert null onerror - but it is not error! The page has been opened).
So, my question is whether it is possible to catch such the situation? I have read some on getting external page content and think it is not possible, but maybe there is another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fetch API to detect if there is any error. Also you can check response.

```
fetch("https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=aGcBwwEACAAJ")
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log("error", error.name));
```

Comment: Not working (at least on my VSCode Live Server) due to missing CORS „Access-Control-Allow-Origin”).